# Postgresql generator column is causing a syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, generator

I'm adding a generator column to a Postgresql v14.8 table using pgAdmin4 with this expression:

```
CASE WHEN columnA > 0 THEN columnA / columnB
```

But am getting this syntax error:

> syntax error at or near ")" LINE 16: ...> 0 THEN columnA / columnB)
> STORED;^

I've looked at multiple examples and can't identify what I've done wrong.

****************EDIT****************

Full SQL code as requested:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."table_name_here"
    ADD COLUMN columnA integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
       CASE WHEN columnA > 0 THEN columnA / columnB
) STORED;
```

Comment: could you provide your whole query sql code

Comment: The CASE statement is missing and END. Besides this, it's not a valid construction: You can't add column columnA and use this column in the generated expression. columnA is the result, not part of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to create a generated column in PostgreSQL 15.4; simply replace "your_table" with the real name of your table.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD COLUMN generated_column numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE WHEN columnA > 0 THEN columnA / columnB ELSE NULL END
);
```